# My Android application is working very slowly

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

I have a 2.67 GHz processor, 4 GB of RAM on a x64 Windows 8 core i7 machine . My understanding is that the Android emulator should start fairly quickly on such a machine, but for me it does not. I have followed all the instructions in setting up the IDE, SDKs, JDKs and such and have had some success in starting the emulator quickly but that is very rare. How can I, if possible, fix this problem?

Comment: Are you using an x86 emulator image, or an ARM emulator image?

Comment: i installed both of them CommonsWare

Comment: I did not ask what you installed. I asked what you are *using*. When you set up an emulator AVD, you choose the CPU architecture of the image. If you are using ARM, switch to x86. If you are using x86, and you are still slow, make sure that you installed HAXM.

Comment: (the difference is that HAXM means you're using hardware virtualization: to slaughter the truth a bit, that means your pc tries to be an android device, instead of running some program trying to be one, that is run on windows that is run on your hardware. Direct (on hardware) vs roundabout method to 'make' an android (virtual) device)

Answer (score 0):

The emulator runs really slow on most computers. I have 8 GB RAM with a 4770k @ 4.2GHz, and it still takes a good bit of time. I just start the emulator when I sit down to work on a project, and leave it running in the background while I work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Android phone available, I'd suggest running your app on the device. It's amazing how much faster it runs.

You also might check out Manymo, which gives you the ability to test of multiple emulators in the cloud. I've only tried it once, but it isn't too hard to setup.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

Go to msconfig and turn off unnecessary applications in start up tab.
When you run an android emulator, turn on Use Host GPU option particularly if you have a powerful graphic card.
Reduce Build Process Heap Size in Android Studio

Go to File->other settings->Default Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Compiler
Change the build process heap size to smaller amount like 512MB from default size of 700MB.
Reduce DEX compiler Heap Size

File->other settings->Default Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Compiler->Android compiler
Maximum Heap size by changing the default value of 700MB to a lower value like 400MB.
Disabling VCS in android studio and using an external program to handle VCS helped a lot. You can disable VCS by going to File->Settings->Plugins and disable the following:
• CVS Integration

• Git Integration

• GitHub

• Google Cloud Testing

• Google Cloud Tools Core

• Google Cloud Tools for Android Studio

• hg4idea

• Subversion Integration

Answer (score 0):

my personal advice is to...

1. at most only one android studio have to open
2. run the application in device by connecting device through USB

because minimum to minimum to work with android our system must have at least 8 GB Ram,with 64 bit and i5 or i7 is ok.

@ASK